# Error: The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, glassfish

Estoy realizando la lectura de [este libro](http://www.ra-ma.es/libros/JAVA-INTERFACES-GRAFICAS-Y-APLICACIONES-PARA-INTERNET-4-EDICION/89071/978-84-9964-522-3) acerca de Java Swing y JEE, y estoy en el capítulo 9, en el cual se comienza a crear un proyecto java web, una base de datos con una tabla telefono, y el entity y session bean de telefono junto a un .jsp formulario sencillo que utiliza un servlet de telefono sencillo.

Cuando voy a ejecutar sobre la APP me falla, pero si ejecutoel módulo war, funciona, eso sí, el envió del formulario al servlet falla y lanza error 500.

---

Estructura

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

---

Traza de la APP.

```
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1.1
GlassFish Server 4.1.1 is running.
Initial deploying AppJEE_rama_1 to /AppJEE_rama_1/dist/gfdeploy/AppJEE_rama_1
Completed initial distribution of AppJEE_rama_1
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
/AppJEE_rama_1/nbproject/build-impl.xml:307: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

Traza del GlassFish 4.1

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option 
MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
objc[88088]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
abr 27, 2016 6:18:53 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner createBundleProvisioner
INFORMACIÓN: Create bundle provisioner class = class com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner.
abr 27, 2016 6:18:53 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
abr 27, 2016 6:18:53 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
ADVERTENCIA: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
abr 27, 2016 6:18:53 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner startBundles
ADVERTENCIA: Can not start bundle file:/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@243dc992 in service registry.
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : rootFolder=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : templateDir=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : src=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/lib/templates/logging.properties
#!## LogManagerService.postConstruct : dest=/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties
Información:   Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (build 1)
Información:   Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
Información:   Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Información:   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Información:   Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 81ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 9ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
Información:   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.1  (1) startup time : Felix (4.690ms), startup services(1.873ms), total(6.563ms)
Información:   JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
Información:   Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@546621c4 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@4e2916c3.
Información:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.7.213:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.7.213:8686/jmxrmi
Información:   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 9ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
Advertencia:   Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn
Información:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   Java security manager is disabled.
Información:   Entering Security Startup Service.
Información:   Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
Información:   Security Service(s) started successfully.
Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
Grave:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
Grave:   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 59 more
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 59 more

Advertencia:   
Grave:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 59 more
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AppJEE_rama_1-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" 
                          fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
                          name="mysql_librojee7rama__bd_telefonos_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="librojee7rama__bd_telefonos"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" 
                   jndi-name="java:module/jdbc/librojee7rama__bd_telefonos" 
                   object-type="user" 
                   pool-name="mysql_librojee7rama__bd_telefonos_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hola dddenis. ¿Cómo es que despliegas la aplicación? ¿La despliegas en otro servidor GlassFish, en un servidor de aplicaciones distinto? ¿Qué configuraciones tiene tu aplicación, puedes mostrar una estructura de sus archivos?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actualizada la pregunta, intento ejecutar el proyecto principal y lanza esas trazas, el servidor es GlassFish 4.1 y lo despliego todo en el mismo servidor local.

Comment: ¿Recuerdas haber definido el recurso con nombre "librojee7rama__bd_telefonos__pm" en alguna parte de tu proyecto o quizás en tu servidor GlassFish como recurso JNDI o DataSource o algo por el estilo?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No, para nada, el '__pm' lo está añadiendo netbeans. He editado la preguntado añadiendo el persistence.xml y glasshfish-resources.xml

Comment: Al parecer en alguna parte está definido el recurso con ese "_pm" de más. Intenta revisar en los archivos de tu projecto esta cadena.

Comment: Excelente!! Tenia el mismo problema, si bien mi app una vez desplegada en el servidor funcionaba bien, No podía hacer pruebas unitarias con el servidor glassfish embebido! Utilizo Netbeans 8.2 y GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0 (build 25). Gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He logrado solucionarlo en **NetBeans 8.1 con Glassfish 4.1.1** de la siguiente manera:

Crear el código XML que represente el jdbc-resource y jdbc-connection-pool, para después agregarlo al fichero domain.xml ubicado en: **/NetBeans/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml**

El código, debe ser parecido y adaptado según el uso a este:

```
<jdbc-resource pool-name="nombre_pool" jndi-name="jdbc/nombre_representante_conexion"></jdbc-resource>

 <jdbc-connection-pool is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="nombre" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="PortNumber" value="3306"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="1234"></property>
      <property name="User" value="root"></property>
      <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="DatabaseName" value="nombre_bd"></property>
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombre_bd"></property>
      <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Una vez modificado, reiniciar Glassfish y funcionará (o almenos en mi caso).

Comment: Excelente solución amigo me funciono perfectamente. Gracias